# lxml: turn webpage source into element tree for scraping

Tags: web-scraping, lxml

Am I missing something - lxml can be used for scrabing web pages, right? I mean, even ones that don't have perfect html? I was using BeautifulSoup, but I'm hoping for something faster.

I swear I read the documentation, but I'm just not seeing how to turn a webpage source into a tree. Everything I read talks about creating your tree from scratch, one element at a time.

I do

```
from lxml import etree

url = urllib2.urlopen(url)
source = url.read()
```

and then what? I can, by the way, turn the source into unicode if that helps.

Comment: Turning HTML to element tree means parsing it. Maybe this is the word you should look for in the docs?

Answer (score 1):

You must use the [`lxml.html` package](http://lxml.de/lxmlhtml.html), a dedicated `lxml` package for dealing with HTML --it's detailed in [Chapter 13 of the documentation](http://lxml.de/lxmldoc-3.0.2.pdf). Incidentally, the package is based on lxml's HTML parser.

**Illustration**

```
from lxml import etree, html

htmltree = html.parse(url)

print(etree.tostring(htmltree, pretty_print=True))
```

In addition, you might want go [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/603630/664424), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3569555/664424) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9920703/664424) to get a sense of how others exploit the package.